# Normalize a "Point"

Tags: c++, windows, opengl, glut

I have a C++ / OpenGl / Glut application that has an orthographic projection.

The window is 500 x 500 pixels wide. Currently when a mouse click occurs, the point will be between (0,0) and (500, 500).

I would like to either take that point and convert it to be between (0,0) and (0,1) (normalize it), or request the glutMouseFunc() send back x and y values in the range [0,1]. Is this possible? Or should I look at a more mathematical way to convert the x and y values one at a time to a normalized value?

Comment: what's the problem with taking window size and dividing it by mouse coords?

Comment: @fazo It would be the other way around, no?

Comment: @fazo: Good call! Would you like to formally answer the question, so I can accept your answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

take window size and divide it by mouse coordinates.

Answer (score 4):

Just divide the coordinates through the window size. Just make sure you keep the window size up-to-date (i.e. hook the resize event.) This has zero cost and there's no way it's ever show up in a profile.